# Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type '(keyof T)[]'.(2536)

Tags: typescript

I am again lost in Typescript. My following code produces `Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type '(keyof T)[]'.(2536)` and I don't understand why. ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPKQLm))

```js
type A = { [key: string]: () => 123 }

function fun<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (arg: keyof T) => 456;
}

fun({ hello: () => 123 })("hello")

function fun2<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (arg: (keyof T)[]) => 456;
}

fun2({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 123 })(['hello', 'holle'])

function fun3<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (arg: (keyof T)[]) => arg.map((key) => arg[key]()); // <-- error
}
```

Is this some kind of distributivity problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have two parameters called `arg`, with he second one overriding the first one.

Essentially, it's like saying

```js
const foo = ['banana', 'corndog'];
const baz = { banana: 1, corndog: 2 };
console.log(foo['banana']);
```

You can't use a key of `baz` ("banana" or "corndog") to index an array of the key of `baz` (`foo`) since arrays must be indexed by numbers.

Below is code that works, change `arg2` to something that makes sense.

```
function fun3<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (arg2: (keyof T)[]) => arg2.map((key) => arg[key]());
}

console.log(fun3({ hello: () => 123, holle: () => 456 })(['hello', 'holle']));
// [123, 456]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBQ5kw)

Comment: Good catch, I shouldn't code until 7am in the morning I guess. ;D Was going crazy because this was supposed to an easy task... Have a good day

Answer (score -1):

when you are accessing the arg obj by using the key in thr map, here key can not be use to index an array because here key is of type key of T .so try the below.

```
function fun3<T extends A>(arg: T) {
    return (arg: T) => Object.keys(arg).map((key) => arg[key]());
}
```